# How to prove that the expression E(z'Az) (for a random vector z) is ...

Tags: linear-algebra, random

I am looking to prove [the following](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_vector#Further_properties)

> Let $z$ be an $m\times$ 1 random vector with $E(z)=\mu$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(z)=V$ and let $A$
>   be an $m\times m$ non-stochastic matrix.  Then the following identity holds
>   true:
>
> $$E(z'Az) = \operatorname{trace}(AV) + \mu'A\mu$$

I am failing to find a straight forward proof to it.

p.s: This is not a homework assignment (although something in my homework DOES rely on this theorem, and I would love to know why it holds).

I reduced the problem to the following: If we call z'=X and z'A'=Y then we [already know that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_formula_for_the_variance#Generalization_to_covariance):
$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = E(XY')-E(X)E(Y)' \rightarrow   
E(XY')=\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)+E(X)E(Y)' \rightarrow   
$
$E(z'Az)=\operatorname{cov}(z',z'A')+E(z')E(z'A')'=\operatorname{cov}(z',z'A')+\mu'(\mu'A')'$
$=\operatorname{cov}(z',z'A')+\mu'A\mu$

Which leaves us to show that 
$\operatorname{cov}(z',z'A')=\operatorname{trace}(AV)$

Can someone please help by showing how this is true?

Is there another direction to this proof that I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the fact that $\operatorname{trace}(AB)=\operatorname{trace}(BA)$, i.e. one can cyclically permute matrices when taking a trace, it doesn't change the end result. Now, since $\operatorname{cov}(z',z'A')=(z-\mu)'(Az-A\mu)=(z-\mu)'A(z-\mu)$ is a number, $(z-\mu)'A(z-\mu)=\operatorname{trace}((z-\mu)'A(z-\mu))$ trivially. Then permute the $(z-\mu)'$ to the back to get $\operatorname{trace}(A(z-\mu)(z-\mu)')$. But the last two factors form just the covariance matrix of $z$ after taking the expectation of course.

Comment: Great answer - thank you!  I keep being amazed at how simple these proofs are once we go into matrix algebra...

Comment: BTW, is it always true to say that E(trace[Az])=trace[A*E(z)] ? (or just if Az is a number?)

Comment: It's true because $A$ is a non-stochastic matrix. And because $E$ can be shifted through any linear operations like taking a trace or multiplying by a non-stochastic matrix. By the way, $Az$ is not a number, it's a column random vector. But $z'Az$ is a single random variable.

Comment: Thanks again Raskolnikov.  It is a pleasure to learn all of these things (and amazing how few of these proofs are documented in the books I am reading).  If you have any good suggestions to books with proofs - I will gladly search for it.  With regards, Tal